# iframe issue for dynamically generated link

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a page where i am generating random pages using php script and that page will be loaded in iframe just like stumbleupon where users can see new page every time.but i tried all sorts of javascript to load new page but iframe shows first page only. however when i see in code part of iframe it shows new link everytime but in browser it shows first page only. i tried all sort of javascript like no cache etc but still no success . any help will be highly appreciated.code i tried are

```
<meta http-Equiv=\"Cache-Control\" Content=\"no-cache\">
<meta http-Equiv=\"Pragma\" Content=\"no-cache\">
<meta http-Equiv=\"Expires\" Content=\"0\">
```

Comment: Can you post your javascript, html and php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround is to just add a timestamp to the iFrame source:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com?v=1331361051"></iframe>
```

EDIT: or in php:

```
echo "<iframe src='http://www.example.com?v=" . time() . "'></iframe>";
```